# Why site looks differ if printed with php?

Tags: php, html, css

I have strange problem, I make for example 3 files main.html style.css index.php,
then when I open index.php which read main.html and print to output I get different appearance than when I opening main.html, do you know what I making wrong ?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>aa</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
a
</div>
</body></html>
```

CSS:

```
body
{
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #f6f6f6;
}

#container
{
    margin: 0 ;
    padding: 0;
    background: #f6f6f6;

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php
 $output = file_get_contents("main2.html");
 echo $output;
?>
```

This main2.html
[image]
This is index.php
[image]

Comment: In what way is it different? Why is it different?

Comment: can you post some screenshots?

Comment: Did you try `include()` instead of `file_get_Contents()`?

Comment: It adds some space in top on chrome and opera, on firefox is ok.

Comment: Is there any space at all at the start of your PHP file, before the opening tag?

Comment: What difference do you see when you use `View Source` in the browser?

Comment: @slugonamission no, I paste here whole files

Comment: Is there a reason your using the "STRICT" <!DOCTYPE> ?

Comment: @j_s_stack I need to build some simple template system

Comment: @Barmar when I get view source code I don't see diffrence but when I inspect element I see some white lines after <body> tag :/

Answer (score 1):

Where you have this:

```
<?php
 $output = file_get_contents("main2.html");
 echo $output;
?>
```

Just simply change to

```
<?php include ('main2.html');
```

Comment: The OP Wants to work on the File Data before outputting it therefore include doesnt work for him

Comment: Do the following... Remove the doctype/<html><head> and just simply left the body tag and it's components from the html file. And add a simple HTML5 doctype and the html/head tags on the php file before and after the php request.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP Require Function.

//PHP

```
<?php 
require 'main.html'; 
?>
```

Also you should set the width: 100% on the header not on the body.

Comment: The OP Wants to work on the File Data before outputting it therefore require doesnt work for him too.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

file_get_contents — Reads entire file into a string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

The include (or require) statement takes all the text/code/markup that exists in the specified file and copies it into the file that uses the include statement.

So better use include or require. Note : I am writing from a mobile that's why it is not so formatted.

I agree with @jordan davis "Also you should set the width: 100% on the header not on the body."

Answer (score 0):

I find solution, i must set php file encoding to ANSI or I set all files encoding UTF-8 without BOM + header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); to php file.

Answer (score 0):

In my last template system I used this function:

```
    private function read_file($filename){
        $code = '';
        if(file_exists($filename)){
            $templatefile = fopen($filename, 'r');
            while(!feof($templatefile)){
                $code = $code.fgets($templatefile, 1024);
            }   
            fclose($templatefile);
        }
        return $code;
    }
```

That works perfectly for me. Insted of `file_get_content` im using `fopen` to open the File and then with `fgets` im reading the Content and finally it has to be closed with `fclose`. See the PHP.net for further Information about the function.

You can also add some Code for a 404 Message if your Template File doesn't exist.